# How can I deploy a SPA on a Wordpress site?

Tags: angular, wordpress, deployment, single-page-application, admin

My question is simple - is it possile to deploy a single page app made with Angular on a Wordpress site, having just an app's code and access to website's admin panel? I haven't found any solution so far. How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You could embed your app using an iFrame:
https://themegrill.com/blog/wordpress-iframe/